# Drawer's ListView doesn't show anything

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm trying to make a drawer for my app, but it doesn't show anything i want it to show for some reason. The console doesn't throw any errors, so i have no idea what happened. Can anyone tell me why?

```
class _MainDrawerState extends State<MainDrawer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
            const DrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.cyan,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'DBug',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('item 1'),
              onTap: () {

                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('item 2'),
              onTap: () {

                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i tried making it both a stateless and a stateful widget, didn't help in either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Drawer` will be showed on parent context scaffold, the place you will call  `MainDrawer`. remove `Scaffold` from `_MainDrawerState` .

```dart
class _MainDrawerState extends State<MainDrawer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: [
          const DrawerHeader(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.cyan,
            ),
            child: Text(
              'DBug',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 25,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text('item 1'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text('item 2'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```